# Get token from promise while sending http.get

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have been trying so long to solve this, any help is greatly appreciated. We have a method that resolves token in promise. After the promise is resolved the token must be added in headers and get request must be sent. The code looks like below

```
// actually this returns Observable<Observable<T>>
// but this is how it should have return type, only Observable<T>
function get<T>(uri): Observable<T> { 
    // create wrapper observable
    const ob = new Observable<Observable<T>>(s => {
         const promise = getPromiseOperation();
         promise.then(y => {
            const h = headers.set('Authorization', y);
            const client = this.httpClient.get<T>(url, { headers: h });
            // now next the actual observable
            s.next(client);
            s.complete();
         });
   });
   return ob;
}

// consumer
get<Apple>().subscribe(x => x.subscribe(y => y));

// How I Actually want to consume is
get<Apple>().subscribe(x => x)

// I also would like to support pipe rxjs operators on the result
get<Apple>().pipe(map(x => x)).subscribe(x => x)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Is it something related to mergeMaps in Rxjs?

Comment: Observable<Observable<T>> Is an anti pattern. You want to use a flattening operator like switchMap (cancels previous request move onto next) or exhaustMap (ignore new requests, finish current one) etc. Any possibility of convert your promise code to observable code (using `from`) / post this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply flatten the chain like below

```
const getApple$ = defer(() => getPromiseOperation()).pipe(
    switchMap(y => {
        const h = headers.set('Authorization', y);
        return this.httpClient.get<T>(url, { headers: h })
    })
)

getApple$.subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

---

### References

[RxJS defer](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/defer)
[RxJS switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap)